# triangle problems

Tags: geometry, triangles, puzzle

So, I was sent a problem by someone. I solved it intuitively but couldn't come up with a logical answer as I got stuck at 1 step.

[image: The original question]

This is how I approached the problem - I drew a side equal in length to create an equilateral triangle coincidentally making an isosceles triangle with the adjoining line segments $MB$ and $AC$. Now I extended the line going from $C$ till it touched the side $AB$. The problem is that when I assume that line to be parallel to the segment $MB$ everything fits in perfectly but I've spent hours trying to prove lines $OP$ and $MB$ to be parallel. Can someone please tell me how I can approach at it to prove that $MB$ and $OP$ parallel.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
Let $AB=AC=1$. By applying the sine rule to $\Delta AOB,\Delta AOC$ we get
$AO=\frac{1}{\sin 150^\circ} \sin 10^\circ, \frac{AO}{\sin(120^\circ-x)}=\frac{1}{\sin x}$, which [yeilds](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28pi%2F18%29%2F%28sin%285*pi%2F6%29*sin%282*pi%2F3-x%29%29%3D1%2Fsin%28x%29) $x=\frac{5\pi}{9}=100^\circ$, hence the desired parallelity.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Important Comment: I messed the labelings, my point A is your C and my point C is your B. In the following I use the labelings as in my picture.**

One way to do it is by trig.  Let $N$ be the intersection of $OM$ and $AC$. 
One way to prove that $AO$ and $MC$ are parallel is by showing that $ON/NM=AN/NC$.
We can compute these quantities by using law of sines.
$$\frac{ON}{NM}=\frac{ON}{NC}\cdot \frac{NC}{NM}=\frac{\sin 40}{\sin 30}\cdot\frac{\sin 80}{\sin 30}$$
and
$$\frac{AN}{NC}=\frac{AN}{NM}\cdot \frac{NM}{NC}=\frac{\sin 60}{\sin 10}\cdot\frac{\sin 30}{\sin 80}$$
Let's start with $\frac{\sin 60}{\sin 10}\cdot\frac{\sin 30}{\sin 80}$ and treat it to convert it in the other expression. 
\begin{align}\frac{AN}{NC}&=\frac{\sin 60}{\sin 10}\cdot\frac{\sin 30}{\sin 80}\\
&=\frac{\sin 60}{\sin 10}\cdot\frac{1/2}{\cos 10}\\
&=\frac{\sin60}{2\sin 10\cos 10}\\
&=\frac{\sin60}{\sin 20}
\end{align}
Now, I am going to use the following (useful) formula: 
$$\sin(3\alpha)=4\sin(\alpha)\sin(60+\alpha)\sin(60-\alpha)$$
In particular, for $\alpha=20$, we have that 
$\sin(60)=4\sin(20)\sin(80)\sin(40).$ Hence,
\begin{align}
\frac{AN}{NC}&=\frac{\sin 60}{\sin 20}\\
&=\frac{4\sin(20)\sin(80)\sin(40)}{\sin 20}\\
&=\frac{\sin 40\sin 80}{(1/2)^2}\\
&=\frac{\sin 40}{\sin 30}\cdot\frac{\sin 80}{\sin 30}=\frac{ON}{NM}
\end{align}
And we are done.